# WebStorm: changing linter underline color

Tags: webstorm

WebStorm seems like *the* IDE for web dev, and I've been enjoying it very much. The only problem is the linter's error underlines:

[image]

Due to such light color I've spent quite some time debugging while the error shouldn't had happened in the first place, I looked around and didn't find a way to change the color. Is this possible in WebStorm?

Even dark themes don't have a harsh and contrasty underline. Can we change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What inspection does the issue come from?

- Place the caret at the highlighted line and press `Alt+Enter`
- Click the arrow next to the inspection to open the submenu, choose **Edit inspection profile settings** to jump to inspection definition
- either choose the inspection severity per instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.3/configuring-inspection-severities.html#change-severity or configure the color/effects used for specific severity as described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.3/configuring-inspection-severities.html#change_highlighting